# Perl file reading have issue while splitting it as space

Tags: perl, file-io, split

I am reading data from a input file and if the line have `Date` in it then whole line need to be taken out and processed. Here in my example `Mem-Id` is unique value and I want to create a hash with `Mem-Id` as a key. As per the data here is the equivalent values for each fields

```
Id -> 1
Mem-Id -> 1
Date & Time (+00:00) -> 2018-07-30T07:40:23
Priority -> LOW
Main Affected objects -> val/s1 val/s0;
Text -> Temperature exceded the limit
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data = <DATA> ;

foreach my $data_line ( @data ){
    chomp $data_line;
    if( $data_line =~ m/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/){
        my ($id, $mem_id, $date_time, $priority, $affected_obj, $text) = split(/\s+/, $data_line);
        print "$id, $mem_id, $date_time, $priority, $affected_obj, $text\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
.............
.............
.............
========================================================
Id Mem-Id Date & Time (+00:00) Priority Main Affected objects Text
========================================================
1 1 2018-07-30T07:40:23 LOW val/s1 val/s0; Temperature exceded the limit
======================================================== 
............
............
```

When I execute the above script I get following output which is wrong:

```
1, 1, 2018-07-30T07:40:23, LOW, val/s1, val/s0;
```

Since there is a space in values of `Main Affected objects`, its been taken as separate values and assigned to `$affected_obj` and `$text` variables.

How can I assign values to `$affected_obj` and `$text` while splitting data line with spaces.

```
Main Affected objects = val/s1 val/s0;
Text = Temperature exceded the limit
```

Comment: @zdim ```Main Affected objects``` and ```Text``` will always have spaces in the values of their fields.

Comment: And how will they be separated?

Comment: @choroba space or semicolon.

Comment: If they are separated by spaces and contain spaces, how can you recognise where the border is?

Comment: @choroba I came to know that ```Main Affected objects``` and ```Text``` will be separated with the semicolon(```;```).

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of keeping things as simple as possible. I think you can do this with two calls to `split()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
  # Split 1: split the text column off by looking for the semi-colon
  my ($rest, $text) = split /;\s*/;
  # Split 2: split the rest of the data on whitespace. But use a split 
  # limit (5) to stop the affected objects from being split apart.
  my ($id, $mem_id, $datetime, $priority, $affected) = split /\s+/, $rest, 5;

  say join ' | ', $id, $mem_id, $datetime, $priority, $affected, $text;
}

__DATA__
1 1 2018-07-30T07:40:23 LOW val/s1 val/s0; Temperature exceded the limit
```

Output:

```
1 | 1 | 2018-07-30T07:40:23 | LOW | val/s1 val/s0 | Temperature exceded the limit
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave. This is most simplest logic. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

> **When in doubt, use a Regex.**
>    -- Benedict IX

```
my @data = <DATA> ;

my $matcher = qr/
    ^ (?<id>(?&token_id))            (?&splitter) 
      (?<mem_id>(?&token_id))        (?&splitter)
      (?<date>(?&token_date))        (?&splitter)     
      (?<priority>(?&token_prio))    (?&splitter)     
      (?<affected>(?&token_objects)) (?&splitter)     
      (?<text>(?&token_rest_of_line))

    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<splitter>   \x20        )   # blank
        (?<token_id>   \d++        )         
        (?<token_date> [0-9]{4} - [0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2} T [0-9]{2} : [0-9]{2} : [0-9]{2} )
        (?<token_prio> HI|LOW )
        (?<token_objects> [^;]++ ; ) # you can get more complex here if needed
        (?<token_rest_of_line> .+ $ )
    )
/x;

foreach my $data_line ( @data ){
    chomp $data_line;
    if( $data_line =~ $matcher ) {
        print Dumper( \%+ );
        # $VAR1 = {
        #   'affected' => 'val/s1 val/s0;',
        #   'priority' => 'LOW',
        #   'mem_id' => '1',
        #   'id' => '1',
        #   'date' => '2018-07-30T07:40:23',
        #   'text' => 'Temperature exceded the limit'
        # };
    }
}

__DATA__
.............
.............
.............
========================================================
Id Mem-Id Date & Time (+00:00) Priority Main Affected objects Text
========================================================
1 1 2018-07-30T07:40:23 LOW val/s1 val/s0; Temperature exceded the limit
======================================================== 
............
............
```

**Edit:**

For more information please refer to [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), esp. the parts about [named captures](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Named-backreferences) and [named patterns](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Defining-named-patterns).

Also if interest: Damian the Great on why [everything you knew about regular expressions is wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubvSjW6Nyqk).

Comment: This answer is helpful. Can you please elaborate what does expressions means in ```qr/.../x;``` and what is mean by (```\%+```) while printing a dumper.